Chrome/Firefox unable to locate Next.js sourcemaps in a monorepo
I am working with the monorepo structure created after using create-next-turbo.
I am struggling to figure out how to get Chrome and/or Firefox to find the relevant sourcemaps. I think I have found where sourcemaps are being output, which is .\root\apps\web\node_modules\next\dist\pages.
For some reason, Chrome/Firefox are unable to locate these sourcemaps automatically (I have verified the option to use sourcemaps are 'ticked' in settings).
I wonder if it's a problem with my tsconfig.json given that there are effectively 3 tsconfigs at play. I know I need to clean this up, and will probably do that next!
root/apps/web/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@monorepo/typescript-config/nextjs.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "next.config.js", "next-env.d.ts", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

root/packages/typescript-config/nextjs.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Next.js",
  "extends": "./base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "declarationMap": false,
    "incremental": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}

root/packages/typescript-config/base.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

